# Modifying SOAP Envelope

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, peoplesoft

I am fairly new with XSLT and wondering how to change the XML SOAP message to add more tags in between

**Source XML:**

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DataValidationFailureFault xmlns="http://sample.com">
         <ValidationErrorList>
            <ValidationError>
               <ErrorCode>1234</ErrorCode>
               <ErrorString>Test Error</ErrorString>
            </ValidationError>
         </ValidationErrorList>
      </DataValidationFailureFault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**After XSLT, I want the XML SOAP to look like:**

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>HardCoded Value</faultcode>
         <faultstring>HardCoded Value</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <DataValidationFailureFault xmlns="http://sample.com">
               <ValidationErrorList>
                  <ValidationError>
                    <ErrorCode>1234</ErrorCode>
                    <ErrorString>Test Error</ErrorString>
                  </ValidationError>
               </ValidationErrorList>
            </DataValidationFailureFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with an [identity tranform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). Then, write another template to intervene in the identity copying process in the right place, namely when the `soapenv:Body` element is processed.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soapenv:Body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <soapenv:Fault>
          <faultcode>HardCoded Value</faultcode>
          <faultstring>HardCoded Value</faultstring>
          <detail>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

By the way, sure you need all those unused namespace declarations?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>HardCoded Value</faultcode>
         <faultstring>HardCoded Value</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <DataValidationFailureFault xmlns="http://sample.com">
               <ValidationErrorList>
                  <ValidationError>
                     <ErrorCode>1234</ErrorCode>
                     <ErrorString>Test Error</ErrorString>
                  </ValidationError>
               </ValidationErrorList>
            </DataValidationFailureFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**EDIT**

> just curious how do I remove the namespace in DataValidationFailureFault tag?

In this case, add another template to the stylesheet that matches the elements in that namespace (`DataValidationFailureFault` and its descendants, too - it's a *default namespace*). Then, construct a new element without a namespace for each of them:

```
<xsl:template match="sample:DataValidationFailureFault|sample:DataValidationFailureFault//*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and modify the `stylesheet` element of the XSLT code to include a namespace declaration for the `sample:` prefix and also exclude this prefix, since it becomes unused in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:sample="http://sample.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="sample">
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias Muller, this approach also works. I am not familiar with namespace but Peoplesoft auto generates these namespace when creating a soap envelope.

Comment: Hi Mathias - just curious how do I remove the namespace in DataValidationFailureFault tag?

Comment: @Kabudles Remove it alltogether? (All descendant elements of `DataValidationFailureFault` carry this default namespace, too).

Comment: @Kabudles Please see the edit to my answer or try it online here: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTg. If you have more questions I suggest you start a new question post so that this doesn't get overly long.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ex="http://sample.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
          <faultcode>HardCoded Value</faultcode>
          <faultstring>HardCoded Value</faultstring>
          <xsl:copy-of select="soapenv:Body/ex:DataValidationFailureFault"/>
        </soapenv:Fault>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Saurav, it works. I have been using a similar approach but I'm using match="/" and it does not work. What does it mean when you use /* instead of plain /?

Comment: @Kabudles "/" means all nodes within the XML."/*" means only the element nodes within the xml

Comment: @Saurav Not really. `/` as the template match means the document node (the outermost node of an XML tree), `/*` means the outermost element node that encloses everything else.

Comment: @Kabudles `/`as the template match for the template above _does_ work in part, it generates the `Envelope`, `Body`, and `Fault`. But the `copy-of`does not return anything because `Body` is not the outermost element. If you change it to `xsl:copy-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ex:DataValidationFailureFault"` or `xsl:copy-of select="//ex:DataValidationFailureFault"` it works. I cannot comment on your "similar approach" of course.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help. This is my first time to write in a community site and never regret that I did.